# Как в Jquery при клике на один или второй элемент выполнялась функция?

Tags: jquery

Как в Jquery при клике на один или второй элемент выполнялась функция? Или лучше назначить им один и тот же класс?

```
$('.elem1', '.elem2').on('click', function() {
    // Код
})
```

Comment: `$(".selector-1, #selector-2")` внутристроки через запятую, а не две строки непонятно в виде чего.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.elem1, .elem2').on('click', function() {
    console.log(111);
})
```

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="elem1">elem1</div>
<div class="elem2">elem2</div>
```